# Chrome Web Developer Tools export 'changes'

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I love the new 'changes' tab in the Chrome Web Developer Tools, which can be used to track which style changes are made locally.

This view seems to be a visual guide only, as copy pasting the results in this view would miss the context of removal or addition (green and red highlight)

Is there a way to export the contents of this tab, so you could save or copy the changes in styling?

I am not asking for ways to save the complete local CSS file, there are multiple ways to achieve that. I'm specifically interested in saving only the changes/diff.